# how to assign a color for particular text in xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

How to assign a color to the particular text. i don't want to use the textview.

Thanks

Comment: You need to expand your question with more detail. Clarify exactly what you want to do. It *sounds* like you really mean, "how can I draw text in a color of my choice?" ... is that what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want use neither UITextView or UILabel you have to create your how view to display the text.

In this view you have to get the context, set the color and then display the text with the function:
CGContextShowTextAtPoint